# Animation effect: breaking button into parts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need an animation effect similar to breaking button in small parts when it is being pressed. Is there an easy way to do it with Quartz, etc.? Pretty flexible on how exactly it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bring your button image into a graphics program and prepare different versions of it, each with an alpha channel blocking out all by a small piece, patterned in such a way that if all the images were stacked, they'd look like the whole button. (For a better effect, you could do a little painting on the edges of the "pieces" so they'd have some modeling.)

You'll need to do a little research on what file format you should use. Probably png would be best, but jpeg might do as well.

Back in Xcode, make CALayers for each "piece" and set the graphic file you created as the CALayer's content. When it comes time to do your "break-up" animation, add the new CALayers as sublayers to your view's layer:

```
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layerPiece]; // do this for each layer
```

And make a CAAnimationGroup of CAKeyframeAnimations -- probably transform.translate, transform.rotation, and opacity -- for each layer. You can find examples out there. Helpful hint: Rotation has to be in radians. You'll need to set your values to have the layers rotate and move apart from each other and perhaps fade out at end. Here's an example of a fade-out animation:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animFadeOut = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animFadeOut.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
animFadeOut.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
```

Finally, for each layer, you set off the animation like this:

```
[layerPiece3 addAnimation:animGroup3 forKey:@"arbitraryAnimPropertyString"];
```

Which is a lot of work. Alternatively, if you have access to a compositing program like Adobe After Effects, you can prepare a movie of the animation (still a fair amount of work, but a lot easier than blindly setting keyframe numbers) and simply play it over the button. I haven't worked with playing movies in iOS, but I assume you'd set it as the content of a CALayer and add the layer to the view to display and play the movie.

Ideally, you'd use 3D software to model, texture, and light the button, particle effects to break it apart, render a short movie, and apply *that* movie to the layer.